# When to join the created threads in a simple multiclient server application in C?

Tags: c, multithreading, client-server, suse

I am writing a **simple multi-client server** communication program using POSIX threads **in C**. I am creating a thread every time a new client is connected, i.e. after the `accept(...)` routine in `main()`.

I have put the `accept(...)` and the `pthread_create(...)` inside a `while(1)` loop, so that server continues to accept clients forever. Now, where should I write the `pthread_join(...)` routine after a thread exits.

More Info: Inside the thread's "start routine", I have used `poll()` & then `recv()` functions, again inside a `while(1)` loop to continuously poll for availability of client and receive the data from client, respectively. The thread exits in following cases:

1) Either `poll()` returns some error event or client hangs up.
2) `recv()` returns a value <= 0.

Language: C
Platform: Suse Linux Enterprise Server 10.3 (x86_64)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First up starting a new thread for each client is probably wasteful and surely won't scale very far. You should try a design where a thread handles more than one client (i.e. calls `poll` on more than one socket). Indeed, that's what `poll(2)`, `epoll` etc were designed for.

That being said, in this design you likely needn't join the threads at all. You're not mentioning any reason why the main thread would need information from a thread that finished. Put another way, **there's no need for joining**.

Just set them as "detached" ([`pthread_detach`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_detach.3.html) or [`pthread_attr_setdetachstate`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setdetachstate.3.html)) and they will be cleaned up automatically when their function returns.

Comment: I have this constraint to my program: "Server should handle all the clients **concurrently**", that is why I am using one thread per client. I am new to both thread based programming and socket programming, so I do not know any other way to do that. (P.S.: I have defined a `MAXCLIENTS` to limit number of threads spawned to a known safe max value)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `pthread_join` blocks the calling thread until the thread exits. This means you can't really call it and hope the thread have exited as then the main thread will not be able to do anything else until the thread have exited.

One solution is that each child thread have a flag that is polled by the main thread, and the child thread set that flag just before exiting. When the main thread notices the flag being set, it can join the child thread.

Another possible solution, is if you have e.g. [`pthread_tryjoin_np`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_tryjoin_np) (which you should have since you're on a Linux system). Then the main thread in its loop can simply try to join all the child threads in a non-blocking way.

Yet another solution may be to detach the child threads. Then they will run by themselves and do not need to be joined.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, the ol' clean shutdown problem.

Assuming that you may want to cleanly disconnect the server from all clients under some circumstance or other, your main thread will have to tell the client threads that they're to disconnect. So how could this be done?

One way would be to have a pipe (one per client thread) between the main thread and client thread. The client thread includes the file descriptor for that pipe in its call to poll(). That way the main thread can easily send a command to the client thread, telling it to terminate. The client thread reads the command when poll() tells it that the pipe has become ready for reading.

So your main thread can then send some sort of command through the pipe to the client thread and then call pthread_join() waiting for the client thread to tidy itself up and terminate.

Similarly another pipe (again one per client thread) can be used by the client thread to send information to the main thread. Instead of being stuck in a call to accept(), the main thread can be using poll() to wait for a new client connection and for messages from the existing client threads. A timeout on poll() also allows the main thread to do something periodically.

Welcome to the world of the actor model of concurrent programming.

Of course, if you don't need a clean shut down then you can just let threads terminate as and when they want to, and just ctrl c the program to close it...

As other people have said getting the balance of work per thread is important for efficient scaling.